# Is this homomorphism in general surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$. Pick a fix $0 \not= a \in I$ and consider the map $\phi: R \to I$ given by $r \mapsto ra$. Is this map surjective?

Comment: I dont think so. But in my case I have a local ring aswell, thus it is possible to pick $a$ to be a unit, then it is true, is this correct? @user26857

Answer (score 3):

No! This map is *not* surjective in general. Example: $R=k[x, y], I =(x,y), a=x.$

*Added:* The image of the map $\phi: R \to I, r \mapsto ra$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by the element $a.$ So the map is surjective if and only if $I = \langle a \rangle.$

Comment: Thanks, this is what i suspected, can you answer my comment above aswell please?

Comment: I see your point, but I cant see whats wrong with my reasoning: If the map is surjective then to every $b \in I$ it must exist a solution to the equation $xa=b$, and it does if $a$ is invertible. Can you tell me whats wrong with this?

Comment: $I$ usually does not contain an invertible element. It does if and only if $I=R$.